# Assembly Binding Redirect programmatically for dll versions

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate, castle

A delphi application will dynamically call a method from a C# dll.

This dll has castle and nhibernate dependency, whose need a binding redirect for mismatch versions.

Writing the binding redirect in the app.config of the dll doesn't work. It only works if the config file is renamed with the name of the delphi exe, but I can't count with that! I'm too not allowed to edit the current application config file, only the dll config file.

Here is an example of what I want:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="AA95F207798DFDB4" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.4000" newVersion="3.1.0.4000" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the Machine.Config file on every client, that's ugly but you asked for it.